# Change alignment of multi-panel plot of spatRasters with different extents (terra), or change borders to fully fill each plotting window

Tags: r, plot, terra

I have a multi-panel plot of maps, and each map has a different extent. I'm using `par(mfrow=c(2,2)` to set up 4 plotting windows, then I'm plotting one map in each (`spatRasters` from the `terra` package. In reality each map is multiple spatRasters stacked on top of each other - I've simplified the example). Here is the example:

```
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
mar1=c(2,1,1,1)
par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,1.5,0))
plot(r,legend=F,mar=mar1,ext=c(5.7,6.5,49.4,50.2))
mtext("Map one",adj=0)
plot(r,legend=F,mar=mar1,ext=c(6.1,6.5,49.4,50.2))
mtext("Map two",adj=0)
plot(r,legend=F,mar=mar1,ext=c(5.7,6.3,49.9,50))
mtext("Map three",adj=0)
plot(r,legend=F,mar=mar1,ext=c(5.7,6.5,49.4,50.2))
mtext("Map four",adj=0)
```

[image]

The maps in the top left and bottom right windows fill the space nicely, but the other two maps have smaller extents and are centered. This means the labels look pretty crappy. I want to either:

1. Align all maps to the left and at the top so they sit nicely under their labels (and any extra white space is all on the right or bottom)
2. Make the outer bounding box fill the entire plot window so all the white space is within the box and not outside it (similar to how it would look if plotted by the `raster` package)

I have looked for a long time and cannot find a solution. I'm specifically looking for a solution for the `terra` package with `stapRasters`. And I want to move the maps, not the labels. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the first option, you can use `layout()`, defining the plotting regions that match the size of each map.

The second option you want can be achieved relatively easily by not plotting the axes when plotting the maps (`axes = FALSE`) and adding the axes "manually" with the `axis()` function.

For consistency, I would define the plot limits first by making an empty plot to ensure that all maps have the same scale and aspect ratio, and then add the maps with `add = TRUE`

If you want map 3 to be zoomed in, then you will have to play with the `axis()` function arguments `at, pos` and so on to ensure that the aspect ratio is the same so it matches the other ones.

Here is a quick example

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))

# bounding box limits and labels positions
xlim <- c(5.7,6.5)
xat <- seq(5.7,6.5, 0.2)
ylim <- c(49.4, 50.2)
yat <- seq(49.4, 50.2, 0.2)

# function to plot bounding box
fbb <- function(xlim, ylim, xat, yat) {
  axis(1, at = xat, pos = ylim[1], cex.axis = 0.6)
  axis(2, at = yat, pos = xlim[1], cex.axis = 0.6)
  axis(3, at = xat, pos = ylim[2], labels = FALSE, lwd.ticks = 0)
  axis(4, at = yat, pos = xlim[2], labels = FALSE, lwd.ticks = 0)
}

mar1=c(4,3,1,1)
par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar=mar1,oma=c(0,0,1.5,0))

plot(1, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "")
plot(r,legend=F,mar=mar1,ext=c(5.7,6.5,49.4,50.2), axes = FALSE, add = TRUE)
fbb(xlim, ylim, xat, yat)
mtext("Map one",adj=0)

plot(1, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "")
plot(r,legend=F,mar=mar1,ext=c(6.1,6.5,49.4,50.2), axes = FALSE, add = TRUE)
fbb(xlim, ylim, xat, yat)
mtext("Map two",adj=0)


plot(1, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "")
plot(r,legend=F,mar=mar1,ext=c(5.7,6.3,49.9,50), axes = FALSE, add = TRUE)
fbb(xlim, ylim, xat, yat)
mtext("Map three",adj=0)

plot(1, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = "")
plot(r,legend=F,mar=mar1,ext=c(5.7,6.5,49.4,50.2), axes = FALSE, add = TRUE)
fbb(xlim, ylim, xat, yat)
mtext("Map four",adj=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, my problem is zooming in on Map 3 because in reality I have many maps all zoomed with different x and y limits, and so manually setting `at` and `pos`  for all of them to get the right aspect ratio is not really an option. I'm trying to find a way to automate that.